# Access an API from local server

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I am trying to call the CTA API (http://www.transitchicago.com/developers/bustracker.aspx) from my local Wamp server. However, when doing the fetch via backbone collection I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/api/v1/getroutes?key=xx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

collection:

```
define([
'models/route',
'core'
], function (Route) {

return Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize: function () {},

    model: Route,

    //url: function () {
    //  return 'http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/api/v1/getroutes?key=xx';
    //},

    url: function () {
        return '/apiproxy.php?method=getroutes';
    },

 });

});
```

I know this is a common issue but haven't found a concise answer yet.

How can I resolve this issue? 
**Update**
Added the apiproxy but am getting this response:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://localhost/apiproxy.php?method=getroutes
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview parsed
GET /apiproxy.php?method=getroutes HTTP/1.1
```

console:

```
responseText: "$url = "http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/api/v1/{$_GET['method']}?   key=xx";
↵echo file_get_contents($url);

SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token $"}
message: "Unexpected token $"
stack: (...)
```

Comment: The server you are trying to access does not allow remote requests value transfer from outside ip

Comment: You should respond on the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * from the server to allow cross domain

Comment: I guess this is because you are doing it from local host but the thing is that the URL you are requesting is not allowing your request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this problem, but it's not a simple case of "add this line to your JavaScript and everything will be fine."

You're running up against the [same-origin security policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) built into every web browser. 'Origin' basically means 'the same site'; my JavaScript on example.com can access whatever it likes on example.com, but it's not allowed to read anything from demonstration.com, example.net, or api.example.com. That's got a different origin. [Here's a table of what counts as the same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules).

Without it, I could write a web page that steals all your gmail and private Facebook photos. My malicious JavaScript would make web requests to gmail.com and facebook.com, find the links to your emails & photos, load that data too, and then send it off to my own server.

Obviously, some web pages are designed to be used by other people. APIs, for instance, generally want to allow access to their data so people can build web apps. The people building those APIs can serve their content with [`Access-Control-` headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers) that tell browsers it's OK to allow requests from other sites. This is called CORS - Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. The reason you get that error message is because the ctabustracker.com developers haven't added any CORS headers. Thus, you can't access their API from your JavaScript.

---

So what's the solution? you have two options:

1. Email the ctabustracker.com admins and ask them to add CORS headers to allow access from other domains. This is the least work for you, but you're at the mercy of the knowledge, infrastructure, & promptness of their development team.
2. Write your own proxy server.

The same-origin policy is only standing in your way in your JavaScript. You can do whatever you like on the server; at its simplest, you could create an `apiproxy.php` along these lines:

```
$allExceptMethod = $_GET; // PHP arrays are copy-by-value
unset($allExceptMethod['method']);
$url = "http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/api/v1/{$_GET['method']}?key=xx&" . http_build_query($allExceptMethod);
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

And then access it from your JavaScript as `/apiproxy.php?method=getroutes`, and pass extra parameters in via a standard query string (for instance, `/apiproxy.php?method=test&foo=bar&cat=dog` results in a request to `http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/api/v1/test?key=xx&foo=bar&cat=dog`). Now your JavaScript is making a request to your own server, so you won't have any problems with the same-origin policy.

You can, of course, make your proxy as smart as you like. It could cache responses, convert your XML to JSON, pre-fetch the results for likely next requests, or 100 other things that may be useful for your app.

Comment: Excellent explanation! Where would my apiproxy.php go in my directory?  The root of the app?

Comment: how do I definethe getroutes method within apiproxy.php? Or does that come from my url in my collection?

Comment: In the example I gave, the `apiproxy.php` file would go in the root of the app. The `getroutes` method is being passed in via the `method` parameter in the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Comment: Your error suggests your PHP isn't being run. You should make sure it's wrapped in `<?php` tags. You should be able to access `/apiproxy.php?method=getroutes` in your browser, and check what it returns (it should look like an CTA bus tracker API response).

If you're not familiar with PHP, then [the tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php) will be worth a look.

Comment: adding the tags did the trick! thank you! Time to read up on php.

Comment: i did some light reading on php but struggling with figuring out how to modify the proxy to deal with my other api calls such as: http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/api/v1/getdirections?key=xx&rt=124
rt is a variable passed from collection

Comment: I've updated my proxy code sample in the original question so it passes any extra variables through to the API.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Should this also work for POST? Im using this proxy on another app and it works for all GETs but fails on Post. URL structure looks like this: https://xyz.dev.cvd.dd.com/rt/rates/EmailService @alex p

Comment: As you might have guessed, `$_GET` stores [HTTP GET variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). There's a [corresponding `$_POST` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) too, but you can't pass those on simply via `file_get_contents`. You'd have to write a different proxy, maybe [using cURL](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).