# Cross-Origin Request Blocked - This can be fixed by enabling CORS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http, cors

I'm trying to do a simple http GET request to the [rotten tomatoes API](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/) in my AngularJS application, but when I run it I get this in my browser console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770672122.json?apikey=[myApiKey].
>   This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
>   enabling CORS.

*Note: the '[myApiKey]' is replaced with my actual key...*

I've tried this with Chrome and Firefox, and while I know there are some parameters that you can attach when starting up Chrome to disable this, normal users won't know how to do this, so from a browser compatibility that option just isn't going to work for me. Also I've tried running my application from my Desktop as well as from a local instance of Tomcat.

So I see that this can be fixed by enabling CORS. Now how do I do this? Obviously I can't touch the Rotten Tomatoes servers so this has to be done from my side - the client.

Comment: CORS needs to be enabled on the server. You might have to write some proxy for this API.

Comment: According to this thread http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/forum/read/129615 someone has already requested this feature ... but they don't seem to respond to the request.

Comment: call the api from server side and access the server side from your client

Comment: So basically as it stands now, no one can create a Angular client for the Rotten Tomatoes API? They haven't responded to the feature request in 3 years, I'm guessing CORS will never be enabled on their side.

Comment: See if you can make a JSONP request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916362/angularjs-how-to-make-a-jsonp-request . API must support this to happen

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718762/access-an-api-from-local-server/24723161) useful, as it's a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [enable CORS on the server-side code by setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP](http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html) or by [changing the web.config](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a `JSONP` request to the rottentomatoes API instead of normal `JSON`.